# How to find a specific element in array (by last modification date and product id)?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is an array with TWO products. The difference between them is in price and last modification date.

```
$array = array(
"0" => array
    (
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => apple,
        "product_price" => 5,
        "date_and_time" => 2017-11-01
    ),

"1" => array
    (
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => apple,
        "product_price" => 6,
        "last_mod_date" => 2017-11-02
    ),

"2" => array
    (
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => orange,
        "product_price" => 4,
        "last_mod_date" => 2017-11-03
    ),

"3" => array
    (
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => orange,
        "product_price" => 3,
        "last_mod_date" => 2017-11-04
    ));
```

My question is how to build a new array for each product in array, where the last modification date has a max value? So, I need to compare each product in array in terms of modification date and then push them to new array ( $products = array(); )

So I'd like to receive an array where:

- An apple where price is equal to six and date is 2017-11-02, because
  the date is greater than date where the price is equal to five,
- and orange where the pice is equal to three and the date is
  2017-11-04, because the date is greater than date where price is
  equal to four

In this case it should look like:

```
$products = array(

"0" => array
    (
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => apple,
        "product_price" => 6,
        "last_mod_date" => 2017-11-02
    ),

"1" => array
    (
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => orange,
        "product_price" => 3,
        "last_mod_date" => 2017-11-04
    ));
```

Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that provides very little informational or educational value but leverages PHP native array functions.

```
<?php

function getLatestById($id, $data) {

    foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
        $idColumn[$key] = $row['id'];
        $modifiedColumn[$key] = $row['modified'];
    }

    array_multisort($idColumn, SORT_ASC, $modifiedColumn, SORT_DESC, $data);

    $k = array_search(1, array_column($data, 'id'));

    return $data[$k];

}      

$foo = [];
$foo[] = ['id' => 1, 'modified' => '2017-11-01', 'price' => 5];
$foo[] = ['id' => 1, 'modified' => '2017-11-02', 'price' => 6];
$foo[] = ['id' => 2, 'modified' => '2017-11-03', 'price' => 4];
$foo[] = ['id' => 2, 'modified' => '2017-11-04', 'price' => 3];


var_dump(getLatestById($id, $foo));
```

So the thinking is, sort by id, then sort by modified. Once you've got a sorted array you would just snag the first occurrence by ID.

For more illustrative code I'd probably write a loop, in it populate a new array using ID as the index. Compare existing value against one iterating on, if modified greater (more recent) overwrite. Something like...

```
$foo = [];
$foo[] = ['id' => 1, 'modified' => '2017-11-01', 'price' => 5];
$foo[] = ['id' => 1, 'modified' => '2017-11-02', 'price' => 6];
$foo[] = ['id' => 2, 'modified' => '2017-11-03', 'price' => 4];
$foo[] = ['id' => 2, 'modified' => '2017-11-04', 'price' => 3];

$a = [];
foreach ($foo as $k => $v) {
    if (empty($a[$v['id']]) || $a[$v['id']]['modified'] < $v['modified']) {
        $a[$v['id']] = $v;
    }
}

var_dump($a);
```

Or leverage your database and don't do this in code.

Comment: Definitely works fine. Your code is useful. Thanks a lot